# How to call a function once for all objects?

Tags: java, class, object

I'm having trouble understanding how I can call a function with multiple objects only once (within a for loop).

I'm trying to write a code where information of the objects should be passed to another function.

Take the following program for example where, instead of once, the function is being called multiple times.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Attraction {

    String name;
    int open;

}

public class attractionGuide {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        attractionDetails();
        System.exit(0);

    }

    public static Attraction createAttraction(String attractionName, int openingTime) {
        Attraction a = new Attraction();

        a.name = attractionName;
        a.open = openingTime;

        return a;
    }

    public static void attractionDetails() {

        Attraction TheEdenProject = createAttraction("The Eden Project", 9);
        Attraction LondonZoo = createAttraction("London Zoo", 10);
        Attraction TateModern = createAttraction("Tate Modern", 10);
        
        attractionInfo(TheEdenProject);
        attractionInfo(LondonZoo);
        attractionInfo(TateModern);

        // This is where the problem is^


   }

    public static Attraction attractionInfo(Attraction a) {

        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Welcome. How many attractions do you need to know about? ");
        final int howMany = scanner1.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= howMany; i++) {

            System.out.print("\nName of attraction number number " + i + "?: ");
            Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String attraction_name = scanner2.nextLine();
            if (attraction_name.equalsIgnoreCase(a.name)) {
                System.out.println(a.name + " opens at " + a.open + "am.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("I have no information about that attraction.");
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

### Example output:

```
Welcome. How many attractions do you need to know about? 3     

Name of attraction number number 1?: the eden project
The Eden Project opens at 9am.

Name of attraction number number 2?: tate modern
I have no information about that attraction.

Name of attraction number number 3?: london zoo
I have no information about that attraction.
Welcome. How many attractions do you need to know about?
```

It seems since the function is being called three times within the loop, it will only take one argument at a time, whereas the desired output should look something like this:

### Expected output:

```
Welcome. How many attractions do you need to know about? 3     

Name of attraction number number 1?: the eden project
The Eden Project opens at 9am.

Name of attraction number number 2?: tate modern
Tate Modern opens at 10am.

Name of attraction number number 3?: london zoo
London Zoo opens at 10am.
```

so how do I go about calling the function once so it takes all the arguments at once?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `List` of attractions as in

```
List<Attraction> attractions = new ArrayList<>();
```

Add each attraction to the list:

```
attractions.add(TheEdenProject);
attractions.add(LondonZoo);
attractions.add(TateModern);
```

Pass the `List` to `attractionInfo`

```
attractionInfo(attractions);
```

Define `attractionInfo` as

```
// Didn't see why you needed to return Attraction
public static void attractionInfo(List<Attraction> allKnown)
```

And use it as such:

```
   Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Welcome. How many attractions do you need to know about? ");
    final int howMany = scanner1.nextInt();

    for (int i = 1; i <= howMany; i++) {

        System.out.print("\nName of attraction number number " + i + "?: ");
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String attraction_name = scanner2.nextLine();

        Attraction lookup = createAttraction(attraction_name,0);
        if (allKnown.contains(lookup)) {
            Attraction ofInterest = allKnown.get(allKnown.indexOf(lookup));
            System.out.println(ofInterest.name + " opens at " + ofInterest.open + "am.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("I have no information about that attraction.");
        }
    }
```

The `contains` assumes the `equals` of `Attraction` is implemented as the desired name comparison.  If you need help with that just ask.  Or search on `[java] equals` in SO.

Answer (score 0):

You need some collection to iterate over, like a List.

```
List<Attraction> attractions = Arrays.asList(
    createAttraction("The Eden Project", 9),
    createAttraction("London Zoo", 10),
    createAttraction("Tate Modern", 10)
);
for (Attraction attraction : attractions) {
    attractionInfo(attraction);
}
```

Or, more advanced

```
Stream.of(
    createAttraction("The Eden Project", 9),
    createAttraction("London Zoo", 10),
    createAttraction("Tate Modern", 10)
)
.forEach(attractionGuide::attractionInfo);
```

Comment: Could this be done with an array as well? Thanks.

Comment: @user17604135 Yes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-do-i-declare-and-initialize-an-array-in-java

Comment: Streams are not "more advanced," they are simply another way to do it.

Comment: @DavidConrad That's your opinion, this is mine. Given that it's using a function as an argument, I think that's conceptually more difficult to grasp than the imperative style.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are calling your loop three times.

```
    attractionInfo(TheEdenProject);  // This creates a loop
    attractionInfo(LondonZoo);       // Ditto
    attractionInfo(TateModern);      // Ditto
```

If you want to loop once, you must call the loop only once.  Try creating the loop and having it call the method that checks the attraction.

```
// Closer to main()
    Attraction a;
    for (int i = 1; i <= howMany; i++) {

        System.out.print("\nName of attraction number number " + i + "?: ");
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String attraction_name = scanner2.nextLine();

        // Add this

        if ( (a = attractionInfo(a.name)) != null ) {
            System.out.println(a.name + " opens at " + a.open + "am.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("I have no information about that attraction.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass an array or collection to iterate over.  the simplest change is below, but you could also use a Map to get the info by name rather than iterating over the entire collection .

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class AttractionGuide {
    static class Attraction {
        String name;
        int open;

        Attraction(String name, int open) {
            this.name = name;
            this.open = open;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        attractionDetails();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void attractionDetails() {

        Attraction TheEdenProject = new Attraction("The Eden Project", 9);
        Attraction LondonZoo = new Attraction("London Zoo", 10);
        Attraction TateModern = new Attraction("Tate Modern", 10);

        queryAttractionInfo(TheEdenProject, LondonZoo, TateModern);
    }

    public static void queryAttractionInfo(Attraction ... attractions) {

        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Welcome. How many attractions do you need to know about? ");
        final int howMany = scanner1.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= howMany; i++) {

            System.out.print("\nName of attraction number number " + i + "?: ");
            Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String attraction_name = scanner2.nextLine();
            boolean found = false;
            for (Attraction a : attractions) {
                if (attraction_name.equalsIgnoreCase(a.name)) {
                    System.out.println(a.name + " opens at " + a.open + "am.");
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                System.out.println("I have no information about that attraction.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, there so many answers.
i think this is your mean:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Welcome. Enter attractions count:");
        int count = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("count: " + count);

        attractionInfo(count, "Jim", 10);
        attractionInfo(count, "Tom", 2);
        attractionInfo(count, "Jack", 4);

        scanner.close();
    }

    public static void attractionInfo(int count, String name, int open) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a name:"); 
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String attraction_name = scanner.nextLine();
            if (attraction_name.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                System.out.println( name + " opens at " + open + "am.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("I have no information about that attraction.");
            } 
        } 
        System.out.println("=================");
    }
```